# Any good POS tagging websites?

Tags: discussion

I thought I had found one that was pretty good (Parts-of-speech.info), but I just entered the sentence "The kids hoot." and it told me "determiner noun noun." If it can't identify "hoot" as a verb...I can't really rely on it for anything.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Most good grammar websites explain the various parts of speech, and the properties that the words require for inclusion in any particular class. "Hoot" is, of course, a verb in your example.

Comment: Definitely. But I'm looking for something where I can enter, say, a paragraph from a novel, and see the entire breakdown of that paragraph. Rather than getting at the broader concepts. Like, currently, I'm going through Cormac McCarthy's Blood Meridian. And you have sentences like "At night the steamboats hoot and trudge past through the black waters all alight like cities adrift."

Comment: Good luck with that!